# How to render content entity as a token replacement?

Tags: entities, tokens

I wonder what's the right way to render entity render array as a token replacement (value). I found 3 different ways in the contrib:

- using `render` method: https://git.drupalcode.org/project/aet/-/blob/2.x/src/TokenReplacer.php#L556
- using `renderPlain()` method: https://git.drupalcode.org/project/token_entity_render/-/blob/2.0.x/token_entity_render.module#L83
- using `renderRoot()` method: https://github.com/goalgorilla/open_social/blob/345bec4e8277e2d2049e2c975eda96f823bfc478/modules/social_features/social_event/social_event.tokens.inc#L160 This last one seems to be causing `LogicException: A stray renderRoot() invocation is causing bubbling of attached assets to break. v Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->renderRoot()` error in some circumstances.

Looking at https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Renderer.php/function/Renderer%3A%3ArenderPlain/9.3.x, it looks like this method should be the correct one, given the description:

> Useful for instance when rendering the values of tokens or emails, which need a render array being turned into a string

Is that true?

Comment: Yes, if you need to turn a render array into a string without bubbling up cache metadata to the page (where it doesn't belong because the content goes into an email), then this is true.

Comment: Thanks. This is interesting, because I interpreted this as useful for rendering the values of token generally ("or").

Answer (score 1):

No, for example the mentioned AET module is mainly targeted to render entities via the token filter in the body field of other entities. Then the `render` method is more appropriate to bubble up the metadata and also not to replace placeholders too early. But this not perfect, either.

You find a better example in the core media embed filter, where in a token you would merge with `$bubbleable_metadata`:

*\Drupal\media\Plugin\Filter\MediaEmbed::renderIntoDomNode()*

```
  /**
   * Renders the given render array into the given DOM node.
   *
   * @param array $build
   *   The render array to render in isolation.
   * @param \DOMNode $node
   *   The DOM node to render into.
   * @param \Drupal\filter\FilterProcessResult $result
   *   The accumulated result of filter processing, updated with the metadata
   *   bubbled during rendering.
   */
  protected function renderIntoDomNode(array $build, \DOMNode $node, FilterProcessResult &$result) {
    // We need to render the embedded entity:
    // - without replacing placeholders, so that the placeholders are
    //   only replaced at the last possible moment. Hence we cannot use
    //   either renderPlain() or renderRoot(), so we must use render().
    // - without bubbling beyond this filter, because filters must
    //   ensure that the bubbleable metadata for the changes they make
    //   when filtering text makes it onto the FilterProcessResult
    //   object that they return ($result). To prevent that bubbling, we
    //   must wrap the call to render() in a render context.
    $markup = $this->renderer->executeInRenderContext(new RenderContext(), function () use (&$build) {
      return $this->renderer->render($build);
    });
    $result = $result->merge(BubbleableMetadata::createFromRenderArray($build));
    static::replaceNodeContent($node, $markup);
  }
```